# version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init) when compiling basic Druid Rust code (Ubuntu, VS Code)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, rust, clion

I've started a new project dealing with user interface, and I chose `druid`, so, as always, I added this line to my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
druid = "0.8.3"
```

...and inserted this code (from druid page on [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/druid)):

```rust
use druid::widget::{Button, Flex, Label};
use druid::{AppLauncher, LocalizedString, PlatformError, Widget, WidgetExt, WindowDesc};


fn ui_builder() -> impl Widget<u32> {
    // The label text will be computed dynamically based on the current locale and count
    let text =
        LocalizedString::new("hello-counter").with_arg("count", |data: &u32, _env| (*data).into());
    let label = Label::new(text).padding(5.0).center();
    let button = Button::new("increment")
        .on_click(|_ctx, data, _env| *data += 1)
        .padding(5.0);

    Flex::column().with_child(label).with_child(button)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), PlatformError> {
    let main_window = WindowDesc::new(ui_builder());
    let data = 0_u32;
    AppLauncher::with_window(main_window)
        .log_to_console()
        .launch(data)
}
```

Basically, this code should display a window with a button and a counter, which increases by one each time we click a button.

Anyways, compiling this code with `cargo run` results in:

```
/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /home/nazar/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
target/debug/feast_rs: symbol lookup error: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: undefined symbol: __libc_pthread_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

It says that there is no such version of glib in /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6. Indeed, there is no such version in it. But when I compile the exact same project in CLion, it works without any trouble!

[image: It works in Clion]

By the way, it appears that CLion uses the following command to compile a code:

```
/home/nazar/.cargo/bin/cargo run --color=always
```

So, I just want to ask why it happens (i.e., why Clion's method can compile it but simple `cargo run` cannot) and how I should fix that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears that it is not the issue with the cargo itself, but instead a problem with VS Code's environment variable GTK_PATH (see [this](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1406))

After running:

```
unset GTK_PATH
```

...the problem seems to be gone.