# version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found

Tags: google-chrome, terminal, glib

In the terminal: I open google chrome as the Default user

```
google-chrome-stable --profile-directory=Default
```

chrome opens, but the terminal outputs

```
/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /home/jk/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so
```

I expected it would read the libraries from /user/lib instead of /snap/core20 where I have everything installed: the apps, libraries etc. I think snap should normally not have been used.

---

First I tried to make a symbolic link from libraries of /usr/lib the ones on /snap/core20/current and some other things, but don't work because the library are always in use, so don't allow writing.

I also tried to make chrome look in the /usr/lib for the libraries. with LD_LIBRARY_PATH commands like (but I don't know if any one can fix the problem).

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu google-chrome-stable --profile-directory=Default
```

this just adds more error output.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76221789/version-glibcxx-3-4-29-not-found-undefined-symbol-libc-pthread-init-when

Comment: It is similar. One comment says it is because i downloaded vs code (I didn't mention that I used the terminal inside vs code) from the Ubuntu (snap) store. And that to fix it, I can download the .deb directly and install it with apt or write the command 'unset GTK_PATH'.

Comment: 'unset GTK_PATH' doesn't change the problem.